# Xamarin forms , Sqlite wait for DeleteAsync

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I learning Xamarin, I use a function to delete all my sqlite database, add new elements and refesh my listview.

the code stop, I thinks it is because it has not time for delete first,add in database then refresh thelist view. When I add a timer (2 seconds) it works.

Here is the error at the line "mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords();" : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

I am using this sqlite plugin [enter link description here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

Here is the function :

```
public async void DeleteAndUpdate(){

mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords(); // the error occur here

List<MyWords> WordUserList = await wordmanager.GetWordAsync(UserConnected.MyId);

foreach (MyWords w in WordUserList)
{
    mywordsdatabase.AddWord(w);

}


var WordList = await mywordsdatabase.GetWords();


Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { WordSList.ItemsSource = WordList; });
}
```

Here is the Delete function for sqlite:

```
class MyWordsDatabase
{
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;

//CREATE  
    public MyWordsDatabase()
    {
        conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        conn.CreateTableAsync<MyWords>();
    }

      public string AddWord(MyWords mywords)
        {
            conn.InsertAsync(mywords);
            return "success";
        }
    public string DeleteAllWords()
    {
        conn.DeleteAllAsync<MyWords>();
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What line does the error occur at?

Comment: @AaronJones at this line "mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords();"

Comment: SQLite has both an async and a blocking API.  If you want to block, don't use the async API.

Comment: @Jason how can I do?

Comment: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#synchronous-api

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of asynchronous methods is that they are asynchronous, i.e. they return immediately while the work they initiated continues in the background. If you call that `DeleteAllAsync` method and then immediately start executing code as though it has finished deleting everything then of course you'll have issues. If you need the deletion to be completed before subsequent code is executed then you need to wait until the deletion is completed before executing that subsequent code. The way to do that is most likely to await the awaitable methods in your code. This:

```
public string DeleteAllWords()
{
    conn.DeleteAllAsync<MyWords>();
    return "success";
}
```

probably ought to be this:

```
public async Task<string> DeleteAllWordsAsync()
{
    await conn.DeleteAllAsync<MyWords>();
    return "success";
}
```

That means that you can either await the call to that method:

```
await mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWordsAsync();
```

or you can trap the `Task` it returns, execute some code that doesn't depend on it completing and then await the `Task` later:

```
var t = mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWordsAsync();

// ...

await t;
```

Comment: I still have the same problem even when I comment the lines after ""mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords();" :"

Comment: it still not works , when I use a timer it works : Task task = null;
int timeDelay = 5000;

if (task == null || task.IsCompleted)
{
 task = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
   await Task.Delay(timeDelay);

   // put the code here it works

    task = null;
}}

Comment: But it is not secure cause if i have more data the time will be long

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check, first of ensure the database actually has words to delete, as the error would suggest that it tried to operate upon a null element. Secondly, since the method is async, see if changing the signature will help.

So instead of `public string DeleteAllWords()` it becomes `public async string DeleteAllWords()` then inside of the method we can say `await conn.DeleteAllAsync<MyWords>();` and where we call it we can then do `await mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords();`

As jmcil said, async code won't wait for its operation to stop execution unless told to do so.

Comment: I still have the same problem even when I comment the lines after "mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords();"

Comment: SO then it would crash on your line to get the word await wordmanager.GetWordAsync(UserConnected.MyId);? In that case, try to get all of the words your sqllite has first and see if there is any data

Comment: it crash here :mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords()

Comment: it still not works , when I use a timer it works : Task task = null; int timeDelay = 5000; if (task == null || task.IsCompleted) { task = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(timeDelay); // put the code here it works task = null; }}

Comment: But it is not secure cause if i have more data the time will be long

Comment: Please don't put chunks of code in comments. It's barely readable when formatted but certainly not when it isn't. Update your question with all the relevant information.

Comment: So okay, if it seems to work when you put a delay then I certainly think it is possible you have a race condition of sorts. Thus, see if you can rewrite your code using things like .ContinueWith. So you will have Task1.ContinueWith(x => Task2). This way task2 will only be executed once task1 is done

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `DeleteAllWords` method like following method.

```
 public Task<int> DeleteAllNotesAsync()
        {
            return conn.DeleteAllAsync<MyWords>();   
        }
```

Then judge the return value if it greater than 0, it the return value greater than 0, it means delete success like this simple code.

```
  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int deleteRecord= await App.Database.DeleteAllNotesAsync();
            if (deleteRecord>0)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "delete" + deleteRecord, "OK");
            }

        }
```

Comment: it still not works , when I use a timer it works : Task task = null; int timeDelay = 5000; if (task == null || task.IsCompleted) { task = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(timeDelay); // put the code here it works task = null; }}

Comment: But it is not secure cause if i have more data the time will be long

Comment: If you have lots of records in your table, this method is time consuming, If you execute the function, you can display a progress bar on the top view.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<string> AddWord(MyWords mywords)
    {
        string result=string.Empty;
        try
        {
           await conn.InsertAsync(mywords);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
    public async Task<string> DeleteAllWords()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            await conn.DeleteAllAsync<MyWords>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }

    public async void DeleteAndUpdate()
    {
        try
        {
           await mywordsdatabase.DeleteAllWords(); // the error occur here
            List<MyWords> WordUserList = await wordmanager.GetWordAsync(UserConnected.MyId);
            foreach (MyWords w in WordUserList)
            {
              await  mywordsdatabase.AddWord(w);

            }
            var WordList = await mywordsdatabase.GetWords();
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { WordSList.ItemsSource = WordList; });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```